# How to do conditional styling in inputs in vee-validate?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs3, vee-validate

I want to add error class when validation is unsuccessful and add success class when validation is successful through vee-validate in my app.

I've input

```
<div id="app">
  <v-form @submit="onSubmit">
    <v-field name="email" as="input" :rules="validateEmail" class="TextInput"></v-field>
     <error-message name="email"></error-message>
       ...
    <button >Sign up</button>
  </v-form>
</div>
```

which submit data on `onSubmit` function, check the validation through `validateEmail`

`<error-message name="email">` gives user error message.

I've `onSubmit` function and validation `validateEmail` as

```
 ....
 onSubmit(values) {
      alert(JSON.stringify(values, null, 2));
    },
    validateEmail(value) {
       if (!value)
            {return "Empty"}
       return true; 
     },
  ....
```

I've noticed that  :rules `validateEmail` automatically sends data to `<error-message>` ,
Here is my codepen [basic-vue-validate-validation codepen](https://codepen.io/lixue2222/pen/jOmWrww)

I've css classes for errors as "has-error" and success as "success".

I'm thinking how can i conditionally  put classes it to input so that it will be styled for error and success?
Like this
[image]
[image]

Thank you for your help

Answer (score 1):

you can have a flag variable (eg: errorFlag) which will be true when there is an error and vice versa and then in the template, have a dynamic class assignment

```
<div id="app">
  <v-form @submit="onSubmit">
    <v-field name="email" as="input" :rules="validateEmail" @blur="checkInput($event, 'errorInput1')" class="TextInput" :class="{'error-class': errorFlags.errorInput1 === 'false', 'success-class': errorFlags.errorInput1 === 'true'}"></v-field>
     <error-message name="email"></error-message>
       ...
    <button >Sign up</button>
  </v-form>
</div>
```

Give appropriate stylings for class 'error-class' and 'success-class'

Create your error flags in the data section of script like

```
data() {
 return {
  errorFlags: {
   errorInput1: null, //Changes applied
   errorInput2: null, //Changes applied
   ....
    }
  };
},
methods: {
 checkInput(evt, key) {
   this.errorflags[key] = evt.target.value === '' ? 'false' : 'true';
 }
}
```

Comment: thank you for helping. I'm not getting where should i put variable , also i have about 5 6 inputs, should i create all 6 variables, this would just slow the system.

Comment: Instead of dom manipulation this is better. Pls check the edited answer

Comment: Hello @amaarrockz thank you. This works perfectly, I've little more concern , like , when user goes to form, the form automatically goes to red, I dont want to make it automatically go red, instead i want to be default and only show red or green when user is writing in form, how can i do that .

Comment: In that case, make your flags as string, have a @blur handler for your input field and define that handler in methods section. I have changed both template and script part. Please check the edited answer

Comment: Hello sorry for again asking, It didint worked., also there was typo eat. 
 I tried to solve ,it didint worked.

Comment: Did you change the template part as well for :class ?

Comment: Check the condition properly for dynamic class binding which I have done